# Recommendation for specific data structure for web development

Tags: javascript, data-structures, backend

I'm brand new to web development with no experience with javascript but experience with HTML/CSS so bear with me here. I'm attempting to create a static website without the use of a website builder by using some sort of front-end framework (leaning towards bootstrap but open to just about anything). One part of this website is going to require a data structure to hold information about multiple objects. For a very close analogy, let's say that I want to store all fruits and vegetables in my data structure. Each fruit/vegetable is going to have multiple attributes associated with it such as color, size, etc. I don't know what the recommended way to store this information would be. Would this require a database created with something like SQL? Should I use a different back-end framework like Django? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some sort of database is a natural way to store data, but beyond that your question is too vague and opinion-based to really answer. Pick something, try it, if it doesn't work (and you can't debug it to make it work) try something else.

Comment: Try to be more specific. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let me be more specific. I'm creating a website that has a list of all fruits and vegetables that shows information about each one. I want users to be able to filter out items by attributes (there are exactly 7 attributes each item has) such as color, size, etc. and also sort the entire list by similar attributes. Is there anyway to implement this on the back-end without using a SQL database? Should I instead hard code every single fruit and vegetable in the front-end?

Comment: Not all databases are SQL databases. The optimal solution depends in part on what framework you use (and the choice of frameworks itself is too important for this particular data problem to be the determining factor). Your data storage needs seem lightweight. A database might be overkill. In JavaScript you could create a vegetable class and just have an array of vegetable objects you populate when the page loads. It is easy enough (Using `Array.filter()` to filter arrays in various ways.